# Question about c++ naming conventions

Tags: c++, winapi, dll, naming, extern

I'm trying to create a abstraction layer for platforms such as win32, mac os, linux, iOs etc.
I want this to be dynamically linked. On platforms that don't support this it shouldn't be a problem since from what I've seen everything that can be compiled as a dynamic library can be compiled as a static one as well with minimum impact on the code.

Now, to get to the point of this:

I created a interface named IThread and a class named CThread. I use a function named CreateThread that's defined with extern "C" to be able to export it and call it outside the library. The problem here is that in win32 for example there already is a function named CreateThread and thus I get a linker error. I understand the error and why it's appearing but I'm not sure of a good way to avoid this. I don't really like to use weird naming as qt uses like CreateQtThread.
Another idea I have would be is to create a thread manager/factory that creates instances of CThread but I'm not sure this would be a great idea.

What do you guys think about this? I'm asking because I don't want to rush on important organizing problems like this.

Thank you very much

Comment: What is your question? You understand the error and u don't want to rename your function, So you want to know what we think about this?

Comment: Yes, I'd like some people with more experience to share an opinion on this, if possible. Thank you.

Comment: Do you want your abstraction layer to be used from C++ only or other languages (such as C) ? Do you want to use it from a given C++ compiler (and recompile your abstraction layer if you need to change the compiler) or do oyu need "compile once works with every C++ compiler" ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I use a function named CreateThread that's defined with extern "C" to be able to export it and call it outside the library.

This is bad. I can't talk for other platforms, but on windows it's perfectly fine to export C++ functions. They are just get mangled, and you get some sanity checking in case someone changes the declaration. In fact, it's the only correct way to export a function that *is* C++. If you declare it as extern "C" you get no namespaces, no overloading, and someone who compiles with `/EHsc` will be in trouble if an exception escapes from your function.

Preferred solution: Do not declare them as extern "C", and put them in a namespace.

The only other solution: well, guess why all those C libraries prefix their functions with `their_lib_prefix_function`...

Comment: There is a good reason why I use extern "C". If I compile a DLL with visual studio 2010 then I can use the dll in visual studio 2008 without having to recompile the whole thing. Practically I can give someone the DLL and the necessary include files (the interfaces) and that person could compile a project using the dll(since the names of the functions aren't mangled) without the actual source files.

Comment: @Sanctus: I think your understanding is wrong. AFAIK the mangling scheme haven't changed in the last 10 years.

Comment: I'm not sure if it changes between different versions of visual studio but it is different on a different compilers like gcc. There is a table here that shows this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling

Comment: @ybungalowbill there are other compilers, even other languages

Comment: @David: given what's written in the OP, you cannot share the binaries among different compilers anyway. The ABI may be different (e.g. virtual tables of IThread).

Comment: ybungalobill: Actually the name mangling is *NOT* stable across compiler versions of visual studio.

Answer (score 5):

Your decision to use extern "C" is sound in my view because it allows access from other languages, compilers etc. But doing so means you can't use namespaces so you simply must prefix your functions with something to identify them as being from your library, a poor man's namespace if you will.

This is the compromise you must make if you want to use extern "C".

Answer (score 5):

Well, I don't know whether you will like this as I know the C developers I worked with found it unaesthetic. But, it's very simple and prevents collisions like this.  (More or less mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7138726/question-about-c-naming-conventions/7138775#7138775) with the "their_lib_prefix_function" comment.)

So, whenever I was using C code, I used to basically 'namespace' my functions using an underscore.  So, let's say your namespace is `MegaAbstraction`, then something like `CreateThread` becomes `MegaAbstraction_CreateThread`.  Easy peasy.  And no collisions, unless someone else has a namespace called MegaAbstraction in which case I recommend finding a namespace that's unlikely to be used by anyone else. ;)

Comment: My +1, I think that is simple and elegant. I don't see any point in being pedantic to insist having the same function name, as: 1. As long as the function name is meaningful, it does not matter. 2. There are 100's & 1000's of things to bother about in an actual project to be fretting over naming a function with a specific name.

Comment: :) thanks, totally agree with you on both points. and, y'know the scary thing is that I think the guys I worked with that didn't like my naming conventions were worried about ... how many extra letters they were having to type. :D I mean, I used to use these super-long descriptive names before it was even fashionable, and though I've cut myself back a bit, I mean... to them if you were looking at their code then it should be obvious to you what kfifl() means and if you can't tell the difference between that and kfifs() and kfifc() and kfifj() meant, then it was your problem, not theirs. shrug.

Comment: I would stay I would hate to work with such folks. I believe a good source is the one which is simple and lucid enough to be understood by the next person who works on in it. Writing geeky code, which no one other than the writer understands is a real maintenance nightmare. Yikes!

Answer (score 1):

Does your CreateThread use the stdcall calling convention (aka WINAPI)? If you use the cdecl calling convention, it should export the function name as `_CreateThread` and avoid the linkage conflict with the Win32 CreateThread function.

```
extern "C" _declspec(export) int _cdecl CreateThread(...
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no "CreateQtThread" function in Qt, not even something similar. There's a QThread class, and it has constructors. If needed, you can put everything in a namespace.